# Maximum value of ode solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

The below problem arises in mathematical epidemiology.
I consider the system of ode
$$\dot u=d u - \alpha uv,\,\,\dot v=   \alpha uv-\gamma v,$$
where all parameters $d,\alpha,\gamma$ are positive.
This system has two stationary points $(u,v)=(0,0)$ and $(u,v)=(\frac{\gamma}{\alpha},\frac{d_1}{\alpha})$

Phase space is picured below

[image]

Let me consider initial conditions: $u(0)=u_0,\,\,\,$  $v_0=\varepsilon\ll u_0;\,\,u_0,\varepsilon>0$ (black point on fig.)

My question is as follows. How to estimate the maximum value of $v$? (red point on fig.)
Of course I can try to find the conservation law $I(u,v)=0$, but this is not always possible.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, shouldn't it occur when $u(t) = \dfrac{\gamma}{\alpha}$?

Answer (score 3):

At all extrema of $v(t)$ you get $0=\dot v=v(αu−γ)$. As $v=0$ is excluded, you can insert the value $u=\fracγα$ into $I(u,v)=C$ to get the corresponding values of $v$.

In general you will not get helpful first integrals, then you can still use the condition $\dot v=0$ with a change of positive to negative at a maximum to set an event for a numerical solver.

Comment: Oh good I was second guessing my calculus skills. I'm glad someone else chimed in with $\dfrac{\gamma}{\alpha}$ haha.

Comment: Yes of course, threshold is $u_{thrsl}=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}$. However, I kind of pointed out that the conservation law cannot be obtained. And at the same time it is necessary to find $v_{max}$. Is it possible to apply the methods of perturbation theory given that $\varepsilon \ll1$?

Comment: The simple Volterra-Lotka system has a well-known first integral. I do not think that you can apply perturbation theory in this setting. As soon as the solution gets large, the perturbation expansion will no longer be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is a LV model. However, I have simplified my original model where the integral of motion cannot be found.

Comment: What is that simplified model? Or do you mean an extended model with additional terms in the DE, because then you can still get a limit cycle, but no other closed trajectories and thus on integral.

Comment: The original model looked like $$\dot u=d u -  \alpha \frac{uv} {1+\delta v},\,\,\dot v=   \alpha \frac{uv} {1+\delta v}-\gamma v$$

Comment: Yes, the second equation destroys the structure that gives the first integral. You could still compute $I(u(t),v(t))=C(δ,t)$ and try to get the lower order terms of the expansion of $C$ in $δ$. I'm not sure if you can get more than improved values close to the maximum with reasonable theoretical effort.

Comment: Lutz Lehmann - Thank you very much!